# Error creating file in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I am trying to create a file in the extension using this code:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
var file = new FileUtils.File("C:\\Windows\\hello.txt");
```

But nothing happens.The file doesn't appear

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your file var is an object that represents a file at the location you specified. Creating this file object does not create a file directly (you might instead choose to read from the file, for example).

You can now use the [nsIFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFile) API to manipulate the file object. For example, you can create a file at that location:

```
file.create(file.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, parseInt("0600", 8));
```

Note that Windows UAC can cause file access to fail. You might want to try:

```
file.isWriteable();
```

but ultimately you might find that it's not possible to write to directories that UAC is protecting so you can instead choose a non-protected location, perhaps using the special directory definitions explained on this useful MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/File_I_O